# How to disable rm -rf /?

Tags: debian

I was working on a debian server, and wanted to delete few things from a folder. 
I accidentally entered `sudo rm -rf /` and that deleted everything from root.

It was a test server, data was not very important.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is that the exact command you entered? What Debian version was that? (This specific command is already blocked.) Are you asking about removal of /, or removal of large amounts of files in general?

Comment: i think i ran `rm -rf /` with root user. and it worked. and deleted everything. debian 9. Is there a way to block it if it is not blocked?

Comment: Why block a command? You should just check what you are doing imho.